# Trigger's updatepanel in a another updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I've two updatePanel :

the first :

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlConso" runat="server" Height="500px" ScrollBars="Auto">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upConsommateur" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
          <Triggers>
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tbLogin" EventName="TextChanged" />
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnValiderAjout" EventName="Click" />
          </Triggers>
          <ContentTemplate>
                            ...
          </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </asp:Panel>
```

and the second :

```
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAjoutConso" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlAjoutConsommateur" runat="server" CssClass="invisible">
                            <table>
                                ...
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnValiderAjout" runat="server" Text="Valider" CssClass="invisible" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

then my problem is when I click on the `btnValiderAjout` the first panel don't update.
I make this button such as a trigger for the first but it don't update ... What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You can call `upConsommateur.Update()` in the code (in the `btnValiderAjout` click handler) to update the panel.

Comment: I've tried this but doesn't works...

Comment: What if you change the UpdateMode of upConsommateur to `Always`?

Comment: Then I do not think there is a problem with the update panels themselves - isn't it possible that for example during `btnValiderAjout` click there is some kind of exception thrown which will prevent the page from processing correctly?